# VS 2012 Compatibility with 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The development team I am joining all use VS 2010 Pro, possibly with TFS or some other SVN system. I placed an order to have it installed but our procurement process screwed up and it seems they have ordered 2012...

Are there any compatibility issues? It seems it will work with TFS 2010 but I remember going from 2008-2010 a lot of programs just broke plus they have to upgrade the project.

Comment: Google can give you the answer, you can google your title...

Comment: @gdoron is right, but anecdotally, I have had 0 problems with it so far.

Comment: @gdoron Could you provide a link? I see this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747.aspx, it seems to be saying that I need to update the project, but I work in a team environment and everyone else has 2010...

Comment: Do you have a MSDN subscription provided through your worksite? If so, you should be able download and install VS 2010 using that.

Comment: @StarPilot unfortunately I don't... I do have a personal license for Ultimate from back in college but prolly shouldn't use that at work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot that's improved from the VS2008 -> VS2010 scenario, and a bit that hasn't (or has gotten worse).

### Project Compatibility

In most cases, VS2012 will be able to open a VS2010 project without making incompatible changes.  The main caveat to this is that the VS2010 user needs to have SP1 installed.

Some project types from VS2010 are no longer supported in VS2012.  The top ones I can think of are Setup projects or Database projects.  In VS2012, these projects simply won't open (but if you don't need to build them, possibly no harm done).

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/28/round-tripping-with-visual-studio-11.aspx for more on this.

### TFS compatibility

VS2012 should be compatible with TFS 2010, but any new functionality in VS2012 won't be available (which is logical since the server doesn't support it).  For more, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788.aspx#compat.

### Runtime compatibility

VS2012 installs .NET 4.5 (also shipped in-box with Windows 8), which is an in-place upgrade of .NET 4.0 - it replaces all of the binaries, as opposed being a side-by-side releases like 3.0 and 3.5 were to 2.0.

There are a few runtime differences that you might encounter in .NET 4.5.  Some of these may be bugs in 4.5 which may be fixed in a future hotfix, and some may be intentional changes (i.e. bugs from 4.0 fixed in 4.5).  The point here being, *if* you do run into one of these issues, your fellow developers might not encounter the same issue.  Then again, if you're planning to support Windows 8, that could be a good thing.

(I don't have a list of known incompatibilities between 4.0 and 4.5... if someone does, please feel free to edit).

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll have to see when it's done installing tomorrow... I would guess VS2010 is properly patched so should be SP1; I think runtime compatibility shouldn't be an issue right? I can just target 4.0.

Comment: @allanx2000 yep, the odds of hitting any runtime issues are very slim.  Just keep the projects targeting 4.0 and both versions will be able to keep working.

Comment: @allanx2000 - Even if you do target `.NET Framework 4.0` you still are dealing with the `.NET Framework 4.0` contained within `.NET Framework4.5` which might or might not include bug fixes. Of course Visual Studio 2010 support .NET Framework 4.5 as long as Service Pack 1 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what features you use in Visual Studio.  In our company, we have not considered an upgrade yet due to 2012 not supporting installer projects (*.vdp) - you now have to use WiX, InstallShield, or some other installer.

Comment: The InstallShield LE from Flexera Software isn't all bad, its pretty easy to set up.

Comment: @Bob. - Anything is better then installer projects that Visual Studio 2010 and earlier supported.

Answer (score -1):

There are compat patches on top of VS2010SP1 specifically addressing some minor pain points for this scenario. You can find those on msdn. Link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082

Other than that things should just work fine as long as you ensure you have the right target framework version and platform toolsets etc for your projects eg. dont target your project to v4.5 since it will not work for your devs using VS2010